# Add a close button to fieldset

Tags: html, css, fieldset

I created the html `fieldset` with some textbox inside. 
[image]

I want to add a close button to the fieldset using only css like this.
[image]

Is it possible? If it is, help me please. Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ukx35/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i updated your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ukx35/18/

```
<fieldset style="position:relative">
  <legend>Title</legend>
     <input type="text"/>
    <button style="position: absolute;right:10px;top:-5px;outline:5px solid #fff">
        <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/hopstarter/sleek-xp-basic/16/Close-2-icon.png"/>
    </button>
</fieldset>
```

use position absolute for the close button and position relative for your fieldset

Comment: Change that to top: -5px and thats pretty much it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But still wondering whether it is possible to break the top line and to place there a close button?

Comment: to "break" the border, you can add a border: 2px solid #fff; to the <button>. updated the fiddle

Comment: @olgacosta Outline would be better, as border will be inside the button. [Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/ukx35/16/)

Comment: @mador, No,no) It's not what I was asking for, I wanted to "break" the border of fieldset from left and right of the button, not the border of the button. Please edit the response back

Comment: @Ruddy was right, i updated the fiddle to "outline" instead of "border". now it doesn't break the button

Comment: @mador Not even a thank you? I pretty much did this all for you! :P